# Check if user exists Registration

Tags: php

I am building a social app in Corona SDK with PHP being the back-end.

I am trying to sign up to the app but a block of code is getting skipped over.

```
if (!$errors) {
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username=? OR email=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['username'], $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->execute();
    foreach ($stmt->get_result() as $row) {
        foreach (['username', 'email'] as $field) {
            if ($row[$field] == $_POST[$field]) {
                echo "Sorry, that " . $field . " is already in use.";
                die();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That code checks if the username or email that was entered is already in the DB. It works fine with my website but it doesn't work with the app. I commented out all of the other echo statements and verified that that specific block of code just doesn't run. Can someone help me ?

```
/*if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST' || ! isset($_POST['Register'])) {

    // Use full absolute URL header('Location: https://www.yoursite.com/index.php');
    //header('Location: index.php');
    echo "Not POST";
    die();
} */

require 'config/connect.php';
$con = new mysqli(...$dbCredentials);

$username = $_POST['username'] ?? '';
$email = $_POST['email'] ?? '';
$pw = $_POST['pw'] ?? '';
$errors = [];

if (!trim($username)) {
    echo 'Fill in username to sign up';
    die();
}
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}$/", $username)) {
    echo 'Invalid username, only letters and/or digits.';
    die();
}

if (!trim($pw)) {
    echo 'Fill in password to sign up';
    die();
}

if (!trim($email)) {
    echo 'Fill in email to sign up';
    die();
}
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo 'Invalid email';
    die();
}

if (!$errors) {
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username=? OR email=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['username'], $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->execute();
    foreach ($stmt->get_result() as $row) {
        foreach (['username', 'email'] as $field) {
            if ($row[$field] == $_POST[$field]) {
                echo "Sorry, that " . $field . " is already in use.";
                die();
            }
        }
    }
}

$ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)) {
    $ipAddress = array_pop(explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']));
}

if (!$errors) {

    $pw = password_hash($_POST['pw'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 14]);

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, pw, ip_address)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $email, $pw, $ipAddress);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $_POST['username'];
    echo "success";
    die();

} else {

    echo 'something is wrong here.';
    die();

}

$_SESSION['error'] = '<b><p style="color: #fff; font-size: 30px; top: 34%;right: 50%;position: absolute;">
' . $errors . '</p></b>';
//header('Location: index.php'); 
//exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should the early returns concept.  First check if there are errors, show error message and exit. If there are no errors then move ahead further to the desired case. This may help.

```
if ($errors) {
    echo 'something is wrong here.';
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Too complicated! I would simplified that like:

```
SELECT COUNT(`username`) FROM `users` WHERE username=? OR email=?;
```

```php
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $email);
```

In PDO there is a function called `fetchColumn()` to get the count as int. Its either `0` or `1`. There should be a similar function in mysqli. I think it's `mysqli_fetch_field()`

username, password and email can simplified as well:

```php
if (empty(trim($username)) or !ctype_alnum($username)) 
{ die('Username is either empty or invalid! Only alphanumeric characters'); }

if (empty(trim($pw))) 
{ die('Fill in password to sign up'); }

if (empty(trim($email)) or !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
{ die('Email is either empty or not a valid address!'); }
```

`if (!$errors) {` can't be false

```php
$pw = password_hash($pw);
```

never store username in session always user id its way safer!

If this should not work try to place an `var_dump($errors)` before sql check.
If this should not work check database connection and bind params values